# How to get all subsidiaries showing in UI by RESTlet in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

i could get all names, types, labels and available options for fields except subsidiary.
There are two options for subsidiary in Netsuite UI. But when i try to get by code, i could get only one subsidiary which was referred in Employee creation.

This is the code snippet.

```
function getFields(datain) {
    var record = nlapiCreateRecord ( datain . recordtype );
    var fields = record.getAllFields();
    var requiredFields = {};
    fields.forEach(function(fieldName){
        var field = record.getField(fieldName);
        if(field.mandatory === true) {
            var id = field.getName();
            var field_details = {}
            field_details['Type'] =  field.getType();
            field_details['Label'] =  field.getLabel();
            if(field.getType() == 'select' || field.getType() == 'multiselect') {
                var Options = field.getSelectOptions();
                var selectOptions = {};
                for(var i in Options) {
                    var opt_id = Options[i].getId();
                    selectOptions[opt_id] = Options[i].getText()
                }
                field_details['Options'] =  selectOptions;
            }
            requiredFields[id]=field_details;
        }
    });
    return requiredFields;
 }
```

How to get all subsidiaries available in lead , customer or contact creation?

Comment: Subsidiary is a searchable record type, so you could just do `nlapiSearchRecord('subsidiary', null, yourFilters, yourColumns);` and get whatever data you need.

Comment: i could get all subsidiary alone. But i want to get subsidiary by the common code. Is there any option or permission should set to get all subsidiaries?

Comment: what do you mean by common code? `nlapiSearchRecord('subsidiary', null, yourFilters, yourColumns);` gives you an array of all subsidiaries.

Comment: Yes i know. There are so many select controls available in Netsuite in lead, customer and contact. I am getting all the select controls and their options by the above common code except subsidiary . There are two values for subsidiary in UI. I could get only one by the above code. Is there any way to get  two subsidiaries by the above code. It should work for all fields.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not clear here, can you please give me some clarity on this . Did you mean subsidiary list in customer,lead & contact or subsidiary list alone on your previous comment?

Comment: In Customer page, Custom form(select) has 2 values they are Standard Lead form and Standard Customer form. Subsidiary(select) has 2 values they are Parent Company and Test_Subsidiary. I got 2 values for custom form and only one value for subsidiary by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsidiaries are retrieved based on subsidiaries set in roles not on employee creation. Here before i have selected only one subsidiary in role.

If we select all subsidiaries for the appropriate role, we can get all subsidiaries which were selected in the role.

[image]